# Custom Login Domain for SalesforceSDKManager

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, ios

I'm trying to get my app to to redirect to my custom salesforce URL, instead of the default one. I can't seem to find a "login domain" option in the SalesforceSDKManager, like there was for the SFUserAuthenticationManager. So, my question is how the heck to do I do this? This is what my set up looks like so far (written in swift)

```
SalesforceSDKManager.sharedManager().connectedAppCallbackUri = CALLBACK_URI
SalesforceSDKManager.sharedManager().connectedAppId = CONSUMER_KEY
SalesforceSDKManager.sharedManager().authScopes = ["web", "api"]
SalesforceSDKManager.sharedManager().launch()
```

Anyone have any thoughts on this (objective-c answers welcome, I'll simply translate them)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is handled via the following key-value pair in your `<appname>-Info.plist` file:

```
<key>SFDCOAuthLoginHost</key>
<string>your_community_login_url_minus_the_https://_prefix</string>
```

You can find more details about it [here](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/mobile_sdk/Content/communities_login_endpoint.htm)

Comment: Perfect. I figured out how to do it by manually setting it in the SFUserManager, but this is a way cleaner way to do it. Thanks!